What are these red pointy flower buds with heart-shaped leaves?
Red semi-pointy buds that remind me of snapdragons but the leaves are shiny green heart-shapes with gentle serrated edges, and seem to be growing bushy.

That's an annual salvia, known as Salvia splendens botanically but usually just called red salvia or sometimes firecracker salvia. It blooms all summer if deadheaded and is, I believe, a good hummingbird plant (been a while since I've planted any - I concentrate more on perennials). Heights vary, but usually are in the 12 inch to 18 inch range, with similar spread, depending on cultivar.
